# Calling two sets of json using D3.json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have currently found myself in a situation whereby, I need two sets of json & functions!

At the moment I have:

```
  d3.json("http://names.json", function (json) {

         });
```

I therefore, wondering whether it was possible two call two different functions & urls, one being a default json (http://names.json) & another being called depending on a boolean.

One idea that I had was to call another d3 method inside the current one, but it didnt work.

I have currently seen only a few jquery examples and none that relate to d3.json method.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `d3.json` twice for each blob you want to fetch:

```
d3.json("http://names.json", function (json) {

         });

if( someBoolean ) {
    d3.json(otherUrl, function (otherJson) {

             });
}
```

Comment: i've been looking more deeply into what would be the most efficient way of doing this. I found Queue.js .. do you know much about that?

Comment: This happens asynchronously, so you can just call both and they will execute at their own pace; a callback will be called when the data loads. That's about as efficient as you can get.